# Generation of Excel sheets in .NET 4.0 in Visual Basic with German functions inside

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel

I have a following problem

I switched our main program, which generates Excel-Sheets, from .NET 2.0 to .NET 4.0 and got following exception

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A03EC): Ausnahme von HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
bei Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.LateBinding.InternalLateSet(Object o, Type& objType, String name, Object[] args, String[] paramnames, Boolean OptimisticSet, CallType UseCallType)
bei Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.LateSet(Object Instance, Type Type, String MemberName, Object[] Arguments, String[] ArgumentNames, Type[] TypeArguments, Boolean OptimisticSet, Boolean RValueBase, CallType CallType)
bei Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.LateSetComplex(Object Instance, Type Type, String MemberName, Object[] Arguments, String[] ArgumentNames, Type[] TypeArguments, Boolean OptimisticSet, Boolean RValueBase)
bei tmd.testing.unity.Excel.xlRange.set_Value(Object value) in C:\Developement\TFS\TMD-TESTING\Main\Unity\unitycoreclass\tmdunitycoreclass\ExcelSupport\xlRange.vb:Zeile 32.
bei tmd.testing.unity.Results.GenericDiagram.FillExcelSheets() in C:\Developement\TFS\TMD-TESTING\Main\Unity\unitycoreclass\tmdunitycoreclass\Results\GenericDiagram\GenericDiagram.vb:Zeile 412.
```

I have a matrix of Objects

```
Public Property Data() As Object(,) = Nothing
```

Which is filled with Double values and formulas.
This matrix is set in the value of the Range property

```
//....
    DiagSheet.Range(dat.Row, dat.Column, dat.Row + dat.Data.GetUpperBound(0), dat.Column + dat.Data.GetUpperBound(1)).Value = dat.Data
//....



    Public Property Value() As Object
        Get
            Return OLE.Value
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Object)
            OLE.Value = value
        End Set
    End Property

Public ReadOnly Property Range(ByVal FromRow As Integer, ByVal FromColumn As Integer, ByVal ToRow As Integer, ByVal ToColumn As Integer) As xlRange
    Get
        Dim Name As String = ColumnName(FromColumn) & FromRow.ToString & ":" & ColumnName(ToColumn) & ToRow.ToString
        Return Range(Name)
        'Return New xlRange(Me, OLE.Range(OLE.Cells(CUShort(FromRow), CUShort(FromColumn)), OLE.Cells(CUShort(ToRow), CUShort(ToColumn))))
    End Get
End Property
```

When I try to set formula as a string (like

```
=WENN((ZS(-5)-P0)>1;ABS(ZS(-4))/(RMF*(ZS(-5)-P0));"")
```

I get this exception.

I found out, I have to use "," instead of ";", that helped against the exception, but I don't see any values in the generated Excel-Sheet any more.
I started translating all the functions from German to English

WENN -> IF or ZS -> RC

But it did not help.

During writing, I recognized, may be I have installed .NET 4.0 in a wrong language? Or how can I bring .NET and Excel to understand German functions.

PS: It is really hard to describe the problem, I hope anybody will understand it. The program itself is very huge and complex to post it here.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: First try to hardcode all formulas to `=1+1` and see if you get anything in Excel.

Comment: It would help if you showed us how you are setting the Formula.  Are you setting the `Range.Formula` or `Range.FormulaLocal` property?

Comment: @Excelosaurus
Thank you for the tip! Yesterday it was already too late to recognize that.
It worked fine. I just mad a sum of some running counters and was able to see the values in the Excel.

Comment: @TnTinMn
The problem is, I have a matrix and only the 7. value is a formula, the rest are doubles, so they are put inside the value directly, without using `Range.Formula` or `Range.FormulaLocal`

Comment: I found out, if I write formulas completely in Englisch, like `=SUM(1,3)` it works well and in the document it sets in the formula field `=SUMME(1;3)`. Something like `=SUMME(1;3)` directly as a formula throws an exception... Means, I have to tell the framework/excel, that I want to write formulas for region Germany, like it is set on my machine... that is a problem. Komma is a decimal separator and semicolon a list separator in Germany. Any idea? 
PS: German languagepack .NET 4.0 is installed.

Comment: I have also recognized, I have to use Formula functions, otherwise Excels sets formulas as a string inside the cells... This is the second problem...